# Need a regular expression to allow only one character in a text box in asp.net

Tags: expression

I need a a regular expression to allow only one character for a textbox. Actually i want to validate a text filed to enter a single charecter for Initial (for name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a regular expression, '.' (dot) matches a single character.
If you want to be sure that this single character is alphabetic, use:

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

or in a posix system: `[:alpha:]`

Now, to know exactly how to implement it, we need to know in which language your code is written.

For a starter, have a look to 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: I don't know vb.net, but I guess that now your problem now is only to check the regular expression I gave ([a-zA-Z]) against your string. Should be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the textbox property MaxLength to 1 and use a regex to validade if a letter.

Comment: the text field is optional one. If user enter a small letter it has to convert to capital letter...i set max length to 1..

Comment: Use something like
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"([A-Z])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);